# Bulk SQL Row Entry with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to make a bulk entry for people with the privilege of team captain for a lunch walk site I am developing for work.

The Captain, will check if a user is to be included in the query, enter the miles for that user, and submit the query. the server pushes those values into an array, and uses a for loop to loop through the form and insert the data into a sql database.

The code below works when you check all members, or just the  1st member in the list.

However, if you leave the first member unchecked it will will not proceed to run the query at all, and not even act if the query is failing. It appears to me that the error occurs right before it tries to run the insert query.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong? Also, other notes on general coding etiquette is welcome. I am self taught so I am not the best with it, and always welcome tips and tricks to make my skill at this better.

Thanks

```
   <?php
                    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
                        {

                        $SQL_Get_Team = "SELECT * FROM User_Account WHERE User_Account_Team_Key = '".$_SESSION['Team_ID']."'";
                        $Result_Get_Team = mysql_query($SQL_Get_Team);

                        echo'<form class="form-signin" role="form" data-toggle="validator" method="post" action="">';
                        echo'<table class="table table-striped" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Miles</th>
                                <th>Include</th>
                            </tr>';
                        while($Team = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result_Get_Team))
                            {
                            echo '<tr>
                                    <td><input type="hidden" name="key[]" value="'.$Team['User_Account_Key'].'">'.$Team['User_Account_Key'].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$Team['User_Account_Name'].'</td>
                                    <td><input name="Miles[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Miles" autofocus></td>
                                    <td style=text-align:"center;"><input type="checkbox" name="include[]" value="Yes"></td>
                                  </tr>';
                            }
                        echo'   </table>
                                <br>
                                <br>
                                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Add Miles</button>
                            </form>';
                        }

                    else
                        {

                            $key = $_POST["key"];
                            $Miles = $_POST["Miles"];
                            $include = $_POST["include"];
                            $length = count($key);
                            for($x=0;$x<$length;$x++)
                                {
                                if($include[$x] != 'Yes')
                                    {

                                    }
                                else
                                    {
                                    if($Miles[$x] == 0)
                                        {

                                        }
                                    else
                                        {
                                        echo 'User: '.$key[$x] . ' Miles: '.$Miles[$x]. '<br/>';
                                        $SQL_Add_Miles = 'INSERT INTO Miles(Miles_User_Key, Miles_Team_Key, Miles_Amount, Miles_Date)
                                                              VALUES("' . mysql_real_escape_string($key[$x]) . '",
                                                                     "' . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['Team_ID']) . '",
                                                                     "' . mysql_real_escape_string($Miles[$x]) . '",
                                                                     "'.date("Y-m-d").'"
                                                                    )';
                                        $Result_Add_Miles = mysql_query($SQL_Add_Miles);

                                        if(!$Result_Add_Miles)
                                            {
                                                echo '<div style="text-align: left;" class="page-wrap">An error occured while updating account. Please try again later.<br /><br />' . mysql_error(). '</div>';
                                            }
                                        else
                                            {
                                                echo '<div style="text-align: left;" class="page-wrap">Updated account.</div>';
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                        }   
                      ?>
```

Comment: A note about StackOverflow: Generally, it's a better idea to ask about your specific problem (i.e. about why it doesn't work if the first person isn't checked) on its own, rather than asking that and also saying "oh and by the way tips on coding are welcome". If you'd like someone to review your code and tell you how to improve it, that's what [Code Review.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is for. You should also provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can see the problem more easily instead of trawling through so much code.

Comment: Yeah this is my 1st ever question, thanks for the advice

Comment: Note on Code Review: We ***require*** code to work as intended *before* posting your code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out by setting the miles form to a value of 0, and removing the include check box..

Instead of using the include check box to check. I simply make sure that the miles field is greater than 0. It feels like a temporary band-aid.. but should work for my current purposes.

I also made the field a number field instead of text, and made it a required entry.

Answer (score 0):

when you run your query(s), add `or die(mysql_error());` to the end, like so:

```
$Result_Add_Miles = mysql_query($SQL_Add_Miles) or die(mysql_error());
```

This will at least tell you what your error is.